# Internet Explorer 11: Children with floated elements inside have a lot of white space when contained in vertical flexbox div

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to fix strange behavior (in **IE11**) of vertical flexbox container children, which stretch in height too much leaving a lot of white space, when they contain floated elements.

[image: Bug screenshot]

You can also see it at: https://kinderhotel.info

So far, I've tried removing `order: 6;` on `.content-5`, setting different values of `flex-grow\-shrink\-basis`, `height`. I also moved `.content-5-inside` up one level in the DOM and then this element had a lot of white space at the bottom. Finally, when I turned off `float` on the divs, there was no superfluous white space.

It works perfectly in modern browsers.

```html
<div class="home-page">
  <div class="content-5">
   <div class="content-5-inside">
     <div class="float-left">...</div>
     <div class="float-left">...</div>
     <div class="float-right">...</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.home-page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-5 {
  order: 6;
}

.content-5-inside::before, .content-5-inside::after  {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.content-5-inside::after  {
  clear: both;
}
```

I cannot use any content managing rules like flexbox inside `.content-5-inside` block, since anything that is inside is provided by end users and can be or not floated. But I need, whenever user puts floated content inside, that there is no white space below.

Comment: The issue seems to stem from the display: flex for class .content-block-5-inside being overwritten by a display: block.

Comment: You have `flex: 0 1 auto` on `.explained`, as soon as I make that `flex: 0 0 auto` in inspector, the problem seems to disappear.

Comment: @Goombah, it's some legacy code, that right now cannot be overwritten and as I mentioned, there should not be any flex rules on this class.

Comment: @04FS - it works when you change it in inspector, but when you load page without these properties, result is the same